# An AppBar application not working correctly in Windows 8.x/10 (desktop working area does not get reduced for multiple appbars)

Tags: wpf, appbar

I have an application that functions as an "Application Desktop Toolbar", or appbar for short. It is implemented in WPF, and appbar functionality is added by following this guideline: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx.

Everything works fine in Windows 7, but in Windows 8.1 (or likely in Windows 8.x) the following happens:

1. The first appbar docked on a display's side is displayed correctly, and Windows desktop's working area is reduced accordingly, so that the appbar does not overlap any windows.
2. The second appbar docked on the same side of the display as the first one is displayed in the right position, but Windows desktop's working area is not reduced. So the second appbar is now overlapping other windows.
3. The third appbar docked on the same side of the display acts identically with the second one
4. The fourth (and all appbars after it) get placed over/under the previous three, so effectively appbars start to disappear

What happens in step 2 codewise is this (debugged in Windows 8.1):

Calling

SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref barData);

returns the correctly adjusted coordinates for the new appbar. But then calling

SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref barData);

does not seem to "go through", meaning that it executes ok, and later the window will be set in the correct position (defined in barData). But the working area is not reduced, which should to my understanding happen by this function call.

What happens in step 4 is, that SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref barData) starts to return incorrect coordinates, such that are the same as already existing appbars. The result being that appbars get overlapped with each other.

The same problem occurs in Windows 10, but seems that with more serious side-effects: my appbar application crashes with multiple appbar instances quite quickly, putting the whole Windows OS to a halt for a few minutes.

I have searched the web quite extensively, but have not found a solution. Did find this article though https://github.com/PhilipRieck/WpfAppBar/issues/4 where the symptoms experienced are quite similar to the ones with my app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My guess is that this is a bug with the SHAppBarMessage API in Windows 8.x/10. But won't stop looking until it is confirmed to be so, or even better, a fix is found.

Comment: Hi Jone, Any luck on this issue? I am also facing the same. We have WPF AppBar application which works fine in Win 7 and got issues in Win 10 surface machines.

Answer (score -2):

In windows 8 and windows 10 ABM_QUERYPOS is not always returning the correct position at first call. But, calling ABM_QUERYPOS again, obtains from Windows the correct position. Depending on the number of app bars.
As a sample, this code obtains the correct position:

```
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP;
        abd.rc.left = 0;
        abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
        abd.rc.top = 0;
        abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height;

        // Query the system for an approved size and position. 
        int top = abd.rc.top;
        for (;;)
        {
            SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);
            if (top == abd.rc.top)
                break;
            top = abd.rc.top;
            abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height;
        }
```

Desktop area is not always correctly modified in Windows 8 or Windows 10 as it is in Windows 7.
For the moment, the desktop area can be adjusted with the next code. In windows 10 avoid using 
SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE, is not working.

```
    private const Int32 SPIF_change = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;

        MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, 
            abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);


            RECT final_working_area = new RECT();
            result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA,
                                                  0,
                                                  ref final_working_area,
                                                  SPIF_change);
            // Verify working area was adjusted
            if (final_working_area.top < abd.rc.bottom)
            {
                final_working_area.top = abd.rc.bottom;
                result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,
                                                      0,
                                                      ref final_working_area,
                                                      SPIF_change);
            }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12880536)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to help, and provide a hint, I hope an expert with enough reputation provide the final solution.I also think there are some bugs related to ABM_QUERYPOS, and to SPI_SETWORKAREA.

Comment: @pslzr : Thank you for your hints. True, calling ABM_QUERYPOS a few times will indeed end up Windows finally giving the correct position. But the biggest problem is with the working area that is not accommodating.

It would be a daunting task to try to handle the working area by explicitly setting it in code, as there may be any number of appbars docked on any side of the display. I think it would be impossible to manage it robustly.

The more hours I have put into this, I am almost certain this is a Windows bug. I really hope for a fix, as this is a huge problem for my app usage.