# Application Desktop Toolbar: Desktop space not reserved by ABM_SETPOS message on Win7/8.1

Tags: mfc, windows-7, windows-10, windows-8.1, appbar

I'm modifying an existing MFC application to make use of the Win32 [Application Desktop Toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/application-desktop-toolbars) API, and I've got a solution that seems to be most of the way there (at least for Windows 10). However, there are three behaviors--on three editions of Windows--that I'm seeing and can't account for:

1. On Windows 7, my appbar positioning code doesn't move the window at all. The style changes for entering/exiting the window's appar mode are being applied as expected, but the window remains in place and the size of the desktop workspace remains unchanged.
2. On Windows 8, the appbar is positioned mostly as expected, but can end up overlapping the taskbar and also doesn't reserve space on the desktop as I'd expect.
3. On Windows 10, a single appbar works as expected, but attempting to pin two appbars to the same screen edge only reserves desktop space for one of them (though they're both positioned correctly).

The code for my implementation is in two primary parts. The first of these is the function for entering/exiting/modifying the current `AppBarState` of the window, which is an enum (wrapped in a class with some helper functions) containing values for each of the window's edges as well as a disabled state:

```cpp
static constexpr DWORD AppBarStyleModifications = WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU;

if (!AppBarState::IsActive(eState_) && AppBarState::IsActive(eDesiredState)) {
    ModifyStyle(AppBarStyleModifications, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOREDRAW);
    UpdateRegistration_(true);
}

if (AppBarState::IsActive(eDesiredState))
    PositionAppBar_(eDesiredState);

if (AppBarState::IsActive(eState_) && !AppBarState::IsActive(eDesiredState)) {
    UpdateRegistration_(false);
    ModifyStyle(0, AppBarStyleModifications);
}
```

In this code, the `UpdateRegistration_` function is a simple helper function for sending either the `ABM_NEW` or `ABM_REMOVE` message, as appropriate. The main 'meat' of the implementation is in `PositionAppBar_`, which looks like this (with some sanity checks and error handling stripped out for space):

```cpp
APPBARDATA Data;
Data.cbSize = sizeof(APPBARDATA);
Data.hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
Data.uCallbackMessage = APPBAR_CALLBACK;
Data.uEdge = AppBarState::ConvertToPositionCode(eDesiredState);
Data.rc = CRect(GetMonitorInfo(*this).rcMonitor).MulDiv(winx::GetDpiScalingPercent(), 100);

SHAppBarMessage(ABM_QUERYPOS, &Data);

CRect WindowRect;
DwmGetWindowAttribute(Data.hWnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &WindowRect, sizeof(RECT));
switch (eDesiredState) {
    case AppBarState::PinnedLeft:
        Data.rc.right = Data.rc.left + WindowRect.Width();
        break;
    case AppBarState::PinnedTop:
        Data.rc.bottom = Data.rc.top + WindowRect.Height();
        break;
    case AppBarState::PinnedRight:
        Data.rc.left = Data.rc.right - WindowRect.Width();
        break;
    case AppBarState::PinnedBottom:
        Data.rc.top = Data.rc.bottom - WindowRect.Height();
        break;
}

SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETPOS, &Data);

const auto TargetRect = CRect(Data.rc).MulDiv(100, winx::GetDpiScalingPercent());
MoveWindow(TargetRect, FALSE);
```

Here, `winx::GetDpiScalingPercent()` is (as the name implies) a helper function for determining the DPI scaling ratio between device pixels and application coordinates.

Although any comments or suggestions on what may be the issue here are always welcome, I'll try to limit the scope here with a few more specific questions:

- Is it necessary to send the `ABM_QUERYPOS` message multiple times to obtain correct results? [This answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154962/1202686) seems to indicate that that is (or at least was) the case, but from my testing, it appeared that the resulting rectangle was the same after sending the message a second time.
- Are there valid scenarios in which `ABM_SETPOS` won't reserve space, and if so, what steps can be taken in those scenarios? I omitted this in the sample code above, but I'm validating the return value of `SHAppBarMessage` and ensuring that the `Data.rc` rectangle has a non-zero size in both the x- and y-axes after sending the message, so I would have expected that to mean that reservation had gone as intended.
- Are there significant differences in this API (or its implementation) between Windows versions that I'm not accounting for here? I couldn't find much documentation beyond what's linked from the [appbar blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/application-desktop-toolbars) linked above, and it seems to me like it should work rouhgly the same across the three OS editions, but that isn't getting borne out by the actual behavior I'm seeing.

EDIT: Quick addendum: `PositionAppBar_` is also used as the logic to handle the `ABN_POSCHANGED` message type.

Comment: How do you define `GetMonitorInfo(*this)`? If you have different DPI settings, try setting Windows 10 to use 100% DPI scaling, see if there is still a difference. Also test everything in single monitor. That's just to rule out the differences between Win10 and Win7 based on DPI settings ...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani `GetMonitorInfo` is a macro defined in winuser.h which is ultimately calling `GetMonitorInfoA` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfoa). As for testing with and without DPI scaling, I've been getting consistent results on Win10 with any level of DPI scaling, including 100%. My Win7 and Win8.1 testing have been on single-monitor machines; I'll see if I can set up a single-monitor Win10 test as well.

Comment: `GetMonitorInfo(*this).rcMonitor` is not a windows API, it must be user defined.

Comment: Ah, you're right; my 'go to definition' tools have failed me in this case (plus I should have paid attention to the fact that the parameter types didn't match up). This API wraps the underlying `GetMonitorInfo` and accepts a `CWnd` reference as a parameter. It calls the `MonitorFromWindow` function with the handle of the passed-in window as a parameter (and the flag `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST`) and then gets the monitor info for the returned `HMONITOR`.

Comment: @bionicOnion GetMonitorInfo is a macro defined in winuser.h which is ultimately calling GetMonitorInfoA.
This is not correct. this macro is defined depending how UNICODE (_UNICODE)  is defined. GetMonitorInfoA if not defined, GetMonitorInfoW if defined.

Comment: @bionicOnion, another correction: " This API wraps the underlying GetMonitorInfo and accepts a CWnd reference as a parameter." is incorrect. *this is automatically casted to HWND type. Dereferenced 'this' is a CWnd object and CWnd class has operator HWND() that does the job. Look in afxwin2.inl line 12 (depending on VS version).